# exc bad access code 1 in prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I ma getting the following error when trying to assign a value to a variable in the destination for a segue

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code1, adderss = some-address)

the code that is causing it is as follow's

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if(testNo < 12){
        let letterTestController = segue.destinationViewController as! LetterTestHolderViewController
        // CRASHES ON THE NEXT LINE
        letterTestController.answer = correctAnswers[testNo]
        letterTestController.testAnswers = options[testNo]
        letterTestController.testNo = testNo
        print("SegueIng")
    }
}
```

It was working fine a while age and i have no idea what is causing this error.

**Edit**

Debugger variable values

[image]

Comment: I would put a breakpoint and check `correctAnswers[testNo]` value at that line.

Comment: @Mrunal I have done this. it does contain an int value. However if i comment this line out it works..

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: @Gordonium i have added an screen grab of the variables in the offending line

Comment: I'm not after the variables, I'm after the full stack trace.

Comment: What about `letterTestController` then? Is that nil perhaps? You're force casting it it seems (as!)

Comment: It is now working again without any code changes